# Trigger spatial join on insert and update

Tags: postgis

I've a problem with a trigger in PostgreSQL.
I can do the query but I don't know to develop a trigger.
The example query is:

```
select schemaA.table1.value
from schemaB.table2
on
st_contains(schemaB.table2.geom,schemaA.table1.geom)
```

where geomA is a point geometry and geomB is a polygon geometry.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select schemaA.table1.value
from schemaA.table1, schemaB.table2
where st_contains(schemaB.table2.geom,schemaA.table1.geom)
```